# generating random number 10 times

Tags: javascript

I am practicing with while loops for an assignment and trying to use Math.random to generate a loop with 10 iterations, so I get a random number every time. Instead I keep getting the same number listed 10 times in a row. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here? Using  in the HTML to display all the results at once.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = 0;
    function showResults() {
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 999) + 1;
    loopOutput = "";
        while (x < 10) {
        x++;
       document.getElementById("loopResults").innerHTML += "<p>Our answer: " + x + ". " + randomNum + "</p>";
    }} //end function showResults()
</script>
```

Comment: FYI, my output is coming out like this:

Our answer: 1. 654
Our answer: 2. 654
Our answer: 3. 654
Our answer: 4. 654
Our answer: 5. 654
Our answer: 6. 654
Our answer: 7. 654
Our answer: 8. 654
Our answer: 9. 654
Our answer: 10. 654

Comment: You will need to calculate the random number *inside* the loop.

Comment: @RobinD. Its usually better to update the question itself with additional information rather than putting it into a comment.

Comment: Ah, thanks to you both! Still getting used to how to use this site.

Comment: Related: [Generating random whole numbers in JavaScript in a specific range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range)

Answer (score 0):

Just move the calculation of the random number into the loop:

```
var x = 0;
function showResults() {
loopOutput = "";
    while (x < 10) {
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 999) + 1;
    document.getElementById("loopResults").innerHTML += "<p>Our answer: " + x + ". " + randomNum + "</p>";
    x++;
}} //end function showResults()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = 0;
    function showResults() {
    loopOutput = "";
        while (x < 10) {
        var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 999) + 1;
        x++;
       document.getElementById("loopResults").innerHTML += "<p>Our answer: " + x + ". " + randomNum + "</p>";
    }} //end function showResults()
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The random number is only generated once when the function is called, but you need to generate number 10 times, so you put

```
var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 999) + 1;
```

inside while loop, at the end it will look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = 0;
function showResults() {
loopOutput = "";
    while (x < 10) {
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 999) + 1;
    x++;
   document.getElementById("loopResults").innerHTML += "<p>Our answer: " + x + ". " + randomNum + "</p>";
}} //end function showResults()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You're generating only one random number. Generate a random inside the loop!
2. Inside the loop you're constantly calling a DOM parser to lookup for your element, instead use your variable `loopOutput` for HTML string concatenation
3. Place your variables within the scope of your function:

Instead:

```js
function showResults() {

  var x = 0,
      loopOutput = "";

  while (x < 10) {
    x++;
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 999) + 1;
    loopOutput +=  "<p>Our answer: " + x + ". " + randomNum + "</p>";
  }

  // Append HTML only once!
  document.getElementById("loopResults").innerHTML = loopOutput;

}

showResults();
```

```html
<div id="loopResults"></div>
```